# Test Int value in Javascript (Regular Expression)

Tags: javascript, regex, int

I have a javascript function which matches the text entered in an Ajax Combobox against a regular expression.
But seems like 'test' is not working as expected.
Below is my code and I am not getting where I am doing wrong.

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function cmbExample_OnBlur() {
        var regex = "^[0-9]{1,10}$";
        var sel = document.getElementById("MainTextBox").value;
        alert(sel);
        if (regex.test(sel)) {
            alert("success");
        }
        else {
            alert("error");
        }

    }
```

I tried converting sel into string then also it is not working.

Comment: what is the input you are giving?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using an actual regex, not a string.

```
var regex = /^[0-9]{1,10}$/;
```

Comment: OP: ..and note that what the regex is saying is "any digit between 0 and 9, repeated 1 to 10 times". You most likely know this, but some people confuse the `{` and `}` operator with the range of the number.

Comment: To avoid heading 0 `/^(?!0)\d{1,10}$/`

Answer (score 2):

That's not regex, that's a string. A regex literal would be:

```
var regex = /^[0-9]{1,10}$/
```

Or you could use:

```
var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]{1,10}$");
```

Incidentally, had you looked in the console (<kbd>F12</kbd> on most systems), the error message should have explained that.

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have been of help! =)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value from the combobox using something like:

```
document.getElementByID("SelectBoxName").options[document.getElementByID("SelectBoxName").selectedIndex].value
```

It's a bit disgusting but it works. You can use .text instead to get the text rather than the value (which I think is what you actually want.)

Also, what the other guys say about the regex statement is true.

Cheers.

Comment: I have used another way of getting the required value from the combobox, and this is also working fine. Thanks!